# How to open a particular form from another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have two Excel files (A&B) which have more than two forms and I need to open a particular form from file B by clicking a button from file A.

As of now I'm opening file B by clicking a button from file A. In file B's worksheet open function I'm opening a form "Camera" only

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Show.camera
End Sub
```

And I want to open another form "Mobile" from file B by clicking another button from file A. Is it possible?

Comment: Obviously what you have here is a non-optimal way of doing this seeing as how you want different targets with different buttons. What other methods have you come up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, theoretically, you need a macro in Book1 to call a macro in Book2

So, in a Book1 module put -

```
Sub callfrm()
Dim wbfrm As Workbook
Set wbfrm = Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\Book2.xlsm")
Application.Run "'" & wbfrm.Name & "'" & "!showfrm"
set wbfrm = nothing
End Sub
```

Then in Book2 you have `UserForm1` which you'd like to show. But you're calling a macro called "Showfrm", so Book2 module has -

```
Sub showfrm()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Raystafarian.
I'm getting error in line **Application.Run wbfrm.Name & "!showfrm"**

Comment: "Run time error 1004"

Comment: I have changed the line **Application.Run "'" & wbfrm.Name & "'!showfrm"** and now its working. Thank you Raystafarian

Comment: Awesome, I updated the answer to reflect your changes